# Vertex label based traversal

Tags: java, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, tinkerpop3, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have a use case to do a traversal based on the label of the vertex for searched name.

For example : There are three kinds of labels Org, Asset and Class(all containing name as the keys of vertices)  in our system.
And if we do a search by name and it finds out to be a Org vertex , I want a particular traversal to carry out , to exclude extra traversal to other vertices.

So in this mechanism when we have to find a label for that vertex a global search has to be carried out which is quite not a solution.

So what mechanism is suggested instead( for this fulltext/partial text search across graph)?

Comment: Could you provide an example graph - ideally with the Gremlin code to generate the graph - and explain the expected result of the traversal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
inject('Org','Asset','Class').flatMap{
  g.V().has(it.get(),'name', 'theNameYouArSearchingFor')
}.
choose(label()).
  option('Org',   someTraversalForOrg()).
  option('Asset', someTraversalForAsset()).
  option('Class', someTraversalForClass())
```

I think that in order to use an index lookup, you need to use the three-value form of has() -- that is, you need to specify a label. But if you want to use an index lookup for multiple labels, you have to do three separate lookups, and combine them with flatMap as presented here.